How can I include the x2 thumbnail preview images again after adding the random products and non repeat random product code?
I am using this to randomize products -
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}

This is the code to stop the randomized products from ever repeating on the pagination -
session_start();

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $sortby = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $sortby;
}

This is the code that did work but is now being excluded (to display 2 additional preview images from the product gallery) -
//* Add gallery thumbs to woocommerce shop page
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','wps_add_extra_product_thumbs', 5);
function wps_add_extra_product_thumbs() {

    if ( is_shop() ) {

        global $product;

        $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

        echo '<div class="product-thumbs">';

        foreach( array_slice( $attachment_ids, 1,2 ) as $attachment_id ) {

            $thumbnail_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' )[0];

            echo '<img class="thumb" src="' . $thumbnail_url . '">';

        }

        echo '</div>';
    
    }

 }

How can I incorporate the x2 image preview into the added code above in order for the images to display again?
A million thanks in advance!!
https://www.skinnydans.com - is the site.
I tried deactivating the code snippets to establish the add image code needs to be added to the random and non repeat random code. This is where I am stuck.
